# How to sign a SFDX Plugin?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, sfdx-plugin

I have created my plugin using `sfdx plugins:generate` and then I deployed it to npm.
When I try to install it using `sfdx plugins:install` I got the message: **This plugin is not digitally signed and its authenticity cannot be verified. Continue installation y/n?**.

So my question is: **How do I do to sign my SFDX Plugin?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salesforce is still working on this and in future they plan to provide a mechanism how extension authors can sign the plugin .

Currently if you want to avoid that warning , it is a manual process .

If you are on MAC you can find the sfdx folder located at below directory

$HOME/.config/sfdx

In the sfdx folder create a file named **unsignedPluginWhiteList.json** and add the below

```
[
    "plugin-name"
 ]
```

Here plugin-name is the name of your plugin .

If you are on windows the sfdx directory will be at C:\Users\username.config\sfdx

or %LOCALAPPDATA%\sfdx

Answer (score 12):

If you need to install automatically your plugin, like in a Dockerfile or in a CI process, you can use the following line :

```
echo 'y' | sfdx plugins:install yourpluginname
```